# cron.yaml in Google App Engine: how to schedule task every hour at specific minute?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, scheduling

In Google App Engine, I'd like to schedule a task every hour at 10 minute. I mean, at 00:10, 01:10, 02:10, ... 22:10 and 23:10 every day: every o'clock + ten minutes. Crontab equivalent will be like

```
10 * * * * mytask
```

What should I write in my `cron.yaml`?

```
cron:
- description: do something
  url: /myscript
  schedule: (?)
```

P.S. Season's greetings, everyone!

Comment: You have all the info on how to write you cron.yaml over here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

Comment: @IdoGreen I've read that, and could'n t find out. I'll read that up again anyway. Thanks

Comment: The documentation doesn't make it clear that the trick in the approved answer is what one should do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
cron:
- description: do something
  url: /myscript
  schedule: every 1 hours from 00:10 to 23:10
```

From [Google App Engine Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron):

> By default, an interval schedule starts the next interval after the
>   last job has completed. If a from...to clause is specified, however,
>   the jobs are scheduled at regular intervals independent of when the
>   last job completed

So, it will run at 00:10,01:10.... etc

Comment: Amazing solution. Thanks!